# switch() based on two vectors

Tags: r

I am building a function run inflation adjustment based on year. The function I have is like

```
    cci <- function(cost, year){
  switch(year,
         '2009' = cost,
         '2010' = cost/1.01298,
         '2011' = cost/1.0455,
         '2012' = cost/1.07334,
         '2013' = cost/1.10387,
         '2014' = cost/1.13042,
         '2015' = cost/1.16645)
}
```

It works fine if I feed it one set of data, say `cci(100, '2010')`. However I want to run it to a vector, like

```
    Cost Year
1    100 2010
2    300 2015
3    222 2012
```

It rises error saying switch() EXPR can only be length of 1.

I tried sapply() it but it returns me a table.

```
    cci <- function(cost, year){
    sapply(year, switch,
           '2009' = cost,
           '2010' = cost/1.01298,
           '2011' = cost/1.0455,
           '2012' = cost/1.07334,
           '2013' = cost/1.10387,
           '2014' = cost/1.13042,
           '2015' = cost/1.16645)
  }

R> cci(c(100,200), c('2010', '2011'))
       2010   2011
[1,]  98.72  95.65
[2,] 197.44 191.30
```

I would like a vecter calculation.

Thanks and Happy Holloween!

Comment: I think you are looking for `mapply`.  Using your first `cci` function, try `mapply(cci, cost=c(100, 200), year=c('2010', '2011'))`

Comment: @bunk work like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapply do the job, thanks to bunk from comments.

mapply(cci, cost=c(100, 200), year=c('2010', '2011'))